# Express and Vue routing pages and API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm using Express as my backend app and Vue on the frontend.
To render the pages I use this wildcard path in Express app:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.write(indexHTML);
 res.end();
});
```

How do I separate the wildcard routing path for HTML rendering and for API requests using the same port?

```
api.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {
 res.json({
  message: 'Welcome to the API'
 });
 res.end();
});
```

Comment: express analyze the routes pattern in order, if you put the api routes before the * I believe should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order or declaration of express routes matter.

If you want API to take precedence, declare it before. Example:

```
// Declared before, takes precedence
api.get('/api/login', (req, res) => {
 res.json({
  message: 'Welcome to the API'
 });
 res.end();
});

// Will answer whatever /api/login doesn't
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.write(indexHTML);
 res.end();
});
```